# Terraform generate dynamic inventory for ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform

can you help me with solving this issue,
i'm using module for creating multiple servers with count.
i get a list in output, how i can send it to file.

```
public_ip = [
  "10.3.1.150",
  "10.3.1.151",
]
```

output inside Module:

```
    output "public_ip" {
      value = vsphere_virtual_machine.linux.*.default_ip_address
    }
```

output to inventory:

```
module "vm-consul" {
  source = "./modules/vsphere-vm"
  vsphere_cluster    = var.vsphere_cluster
  vsphere_folder                    = var.vsphere_folder
  vsphere_template   = var.vsphere_template
  ipv4_gateway                   = var.ipv4_gateway
  dns_server_list                = var.dns_server_list
  vm_instances           = var.consul.vm_instances
  vm_name             = var.consul.vm_name
  vm_network          = var.consul.vm_network
  vm_num_cpus             = var.consul.vm_num_cpus
  vm_num_cores_per_socket = var.consul.vm_num_cores_per_socket
  vm_memory           = var.consul.vm_memory
  vm_disks        = var.consul.vm_disks
  vm_enable_disk_uuid = var.consul.vm_enable_disk_uuid
  vm_ipv4submask         = var.vm_ipv4submask
}
output "public_ip" {
  value = try(
    module.vm-consul.public_ip,
    null,
  )
}

data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  template = file("ansible_inventory.tpl")
  vars = {
    consul-ip = module.vm-consul.public_ip
  }
}
```

#### ERROR

```
 Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on output.tf line 11, in data "template_file" "ansible_inventory":
│   11:   vars = {
│   12:     consul-ip = module.vm-consul.public_ip
│   13:   }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vm-consul.public_ip is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "consul-ip": string required.
```

Comment: The template_file data source expects a string value for each of its vars attributes, but you're passing a list of strings (tuple) from the module.vm-consul.public_ip output.
If you want to concatenate all the IPs into a single string, you could use the [join](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/join) function.
If you want to handle each IP separately, you might need a different approach, like multiple template_file data sources or restructuring your template. For example, adjust your template, and create a template_file data source for each IP.

Comment: thx, issue was with tpl file, i should just use like it - ``` [cluster_nodes]
%{ for cluster_nodes_ip in cluster_nodes_ips ~}
${cluster_nodes_ip}
%{ endfor ~} ```

Answer (score 2):

`vsphere_virtual_machine.linux.*.default_ip_address` returns a list/tuple of `default_ip_address`. So you either have to use specific instance of the `default_ip_address` or use `count` (or `for_each`):

```
data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {

  count = length(module.vm-consul.public_ip)
  
  template = file("ansible_inventory.tpl")
  vars = {
    consul-ip = module.vm-consul[count.index].public_ip
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ansible.tpl
[cluster_nodes]
%{ for cluster_nodes_ip in cluster_nodes_ips ~}
${cluster_nodes_ip}
%{ endfor ~}

# inventory from list
resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  content     = templatefile("ansible.tpl", 
    { 
      cluster_nodes_ips = module.vm-consul.public_ip
    })
  filename    = "inventory"
}
```